# The issue with visibility:hidden property and useEffect in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have an issue with the CSS property `visibility: hidden;` and `useEffect`.
I have a simple component with two `divs` inside of it. Each `div` has a text. I want to split the letters and add a `span` for each. It actually works. But if I add `visibility: hidden;`, the letters don't exist.
Here is my component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const splitRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const divs = splitRef.current.querySelectorAll("div");
    divs.forEach((item) => {
      let newInnerText = "";
      const letters = item.innerText.split("");
      letters.forEach((letter) => {
        newInnerText += `<span>${letter}</span>`;
      });
      item.innerHTML = newInnerText;
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={splitRef} style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>
        <div>CONTACT</div>
        <div>ABOUT</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

And I display it in my index.js:

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't have errors, and without visibility: hidden; I have:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>C</span><span>O</span><span>N</span><span>T</span><span>A</span><span>C</span><span>T</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>A</span><span>B</span><span>O</span><span>U</span><span>T</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

With visibility: hidden; I have empty divs:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I tried to use useLayoutEffect, but nothing changed. And it doesn't matter if I use `visibility: hidden;` in CSS file. And I need `visibility: hidden;` for future animations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to not use `querySelector...` or any of the `getElement...` functions in React.

I solved this using a custom component which only returns its `children`. We map over the children, if the child element is a `div` we get the text create a `span` for all letters and return the modified child.

```js
const SpanTextComponent = ({ children }) => {
  // map over the children
  const childrenWithSpanText = children.map((child) => {
    // if the child element is not of type 'div' return the child
    if (child.type !== "div") return child;

    // get the text from the child
    const text = child.props.children;
    // map over all the characters in the text
    const spans = text.split("").map((letter, idx) => {
      // create a new span element with the letter and a key
      const span = React.createElement("span", {
        children: letter,
        key: letter + idx,
      });
      // return the new span
      return span;
    });

    // copy the child and add the new spans as children
    const newChild = {
      ...child,
      props: {
        ...child.props,
        children: spans,
      },
    };

    // return the new child
    return newChild;
  });

  // return the modified children
  return childrenWithSpanText;
};
```

You can use this like

```js
<div style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>
  <SpanTextComponent>
    <div>CONTACT</div>
    <div>ABOUT</div>
  </SpanTextComponent>
</div>
```